# Spring RabbitMQ - is a queue configuration with no exchanges possible

Tags: java, spring, configuration, rabbitmq

Here is an existing spring rabbit config from a project that I inherited -

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
    host="${rabbitmq.host}"
    port="${rabbitmq.port}"
    virtual-host="${rabbitmq.virtualHost}"
    username="${rabbitmq.username}"
    password="${rabbitmq.password}"/> 

<rabbit:template id="ampqTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" routing-key="" />
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" />
<rabbit:queue name="${rabbitmq.queueName}"   />
```

I dont have experience using Rabbit and with my limited reference,
 I understand an exchange is an important piece in the setup since it relays messages to the queue internally.

However, the above configuration does not contain any exchange information.

My Questions are :

1. Is an exchange absolutely important for even  a simple queue configuration.?
2. Is there any implication of not defining an exchange
3. Is there anyother configuration obviously missing from the above configuration?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't define an exchange the default exchange will be used. It is a direct exchange which will use the name of the queue as its routing key.

It doesn't look like there is anything missing from your configuration. Mine is:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="${rabbit.host}" username="${rabbit.username}" password="${rabbit.password}" virtual-host="${rabbit.vhost}"/>
<rabbit:template id="rabbitTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" routing-key="event-queue"/>
```

You may be able to take the `rabbit:queue` definition out and use the queue name as the routing key for the `rabbit:template`.